# How to set value for dropdownlist in jsp?

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

am having the following jsp tag to display arraylist values.whereas the `zoneInformation` contains `[North, South, East, West]`.

```
<html:form action="addcountry">
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html:select property="zone" styleClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">     
<%  ArrayList ls = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("zoneInformation");
for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
%>
<html:option value=" "><%=ls.get(i)%></html:option> 
<%}%>
</html:select>
</html:form>
```

how to set values to this dropdown list....?

Answer (score 0):

First, prefer JSTL: `c:forEach` instead of scrptlets.

Then, you can just set the value to be the same as the displayed label.

Then, you can use `<html:options collection="${zoneInformation} />` without any loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `html:select` tag will make the option with the same value as its property attribute value selected automatically. So, in your code, the zone information with the value `" "` will be selected. This means that if you want some option selected, its value should be equal to the `zone` property of the form bean.

And please, don't use scriptlets. Use the JSTL and the EL.

Comment: JSTL is simply amazing....! and mycode is working fine!! Thanks for ur help!!! :-)